# Swift table view background for empty rows and section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a table view controller with a header that I want to give a certain  background color. I also want the text "John Doe" to be perfectly aligned with the menu icon, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

To make sure "John Doe" is perfectly aligned with the menu icon, and to set the correct background color, I use the following code:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
        tableView.contentInset = inset

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.64, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

The status bar ("Carrier / 8:57 AM") height is 20, so the inset is needed to make sure John Doe is correctly aligned.

That works great, but now the empty rows are also in this background color. I have tried adding an empty view under the "Logout" button and give it the same color as the rows, but I can't seem to stretch this all the way to the bottom of the table view controller.

I have also tried setting the background color of the table header, but that won't work because then the status bar does not have the correct background color (because of the inset).

How can I make sure everything beneath the Logout button is in the same background color as the actual rows?

Edit: Setting the background color of the table results in this:
[image: Screenshot]

Now the status bar also has this color, because of the inset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any of the suggestions to work, so I just create a table footer which fills up the rest of the screen:

```
var menuItems = ["Dial", "Settings", "CallHistory", "Logout"]
let headerHeight = CGFloat(64)
let cellHeight = 56

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
    let totalMenuItemHeight = menuItems.count * cellHeight

    tableView.contentInset = inset
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.64, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.tableFooterView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.98, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1.0)
    tableView.tableFooterView!.frame.size.height = tableView.frame.height - CGFloat(headerHeight) - CGFloat(totalMenuItemHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tableView.backgroundColor`you are setting the background color to the whole tableview and this works for the header just because it has `UIColor.clearColor()` (transparent) as default color.

If you want all the table in lightGrey and just the header in that dark grey you need to set the table background the same of the cells and then implement [`willDisplayHeaderView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:) just for setting that header color:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView,
               forSection section: Int){
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.63, green: 0.64, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: Updated my post with the result of that. The statusbar is now in that color as well. Is there a way to change that back to black from within the table view controller?

Comment: What if you set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` for your `UITableViewController`? You Have to set the backgroundColor of your application window appropriate(in your case the color of your header). But it will change the color of your right statusbar too then i think.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, also the background color is correct. Same result as in my 2nd screenshot.

Comment: How do you display your tableview controller? Inside a UINavigationController as root or just as root for your window?

Comment: Inside UINavigationController

Comment: Set the backgroundColor of the navigationController to the gray of your header and don't set a contentInset for your tableview. Then you should have the gray statusbar matching your header. But when scrolling the header would disconnect from the statusbar and you would see a white background between status bar and header